# How to sort an arraylist by multiple fields in Typescript

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, typescript

How can I sort an arraylist in Typescript by multiple fields.

For example, I have this object:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eii9g.png)

My single sort method works fine:

```
private sortFunction(a: RSFolderObject, b: RSFolderObject) {
    var a_label = a.label.toLowerCase();
    var b_label = b.label.toLowerCase();

    if (a_label < b_label) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a_label > b_label) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For multiple sorting I used that:

```
private sortFunction(a: RSFolderObject, b: RSFolderObject) {
    var a_label = a.label.toLowerCase();
    var b_label = b.label.toLowerCase();
    var a_description = a.description[0].toLowerCase().replace("\\", "");
    var b_description = b.description[0].toLowerCase().replace("\\", "");

    if (a_label < b_label || a_description < b_description) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a_label > b_label || a_description > b_description) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: How exactly do you sort? What are you sorting? All you showed here is the compare function, but what do you do with it? Also, can you elaborate a bit more about what doesn't work?

Comment: I have an object "RSFolderObject". You can see the image above in the link. That is the Object that I will sort. 1) var myObject: RSFolderObject[] = []; 2).....than push the existing object to myObject..... 3) myObject.sort(this.sortFunction);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved it like this:

```
private sortFunction(a: RSFolderObject, b: RSFolderObject) {

    var a_label = a.label.toLowerCase();
    var b_label = b.label.toLowerCase();
    var a_description = a.description[0].toLowerCase().replace("\\", "");
    var b_description = b.description[0].toLowerCase().replace("\\", "");

        if (a_label < b_label) {
                return -1;
            }
        else if (a_label > b_label) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            if (a_description < b_description) {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (a_description > b_description) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp because localeCompare should eliminate most of this code (return str1.localeCompare(str2)).  Also, string.match with the /i option might be better for case-insensitive testing.